# Приоритетность рекурсии и цикла for C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, функции, циклы, рекурсия

Задача в том, чтобы разместить ферзей так, чтобы они друг друга не били. Вот есть псевдокод:

```
PlaceQueens(Q[1 .. n],r):
  if r = n + 1
    print Q[1 .. n]
  else
    for j = 1 to n
      legal = True
      for i = 1 to r - 1
        if (Q[i] = j) or (Q[i] = j + r - i) or (Q[i] = j - r + i)
          legal = False
      if legal
        Q[r] = j
        PlaceQueens(Q[1 .. n],r + 1)
```

что будет выполняться первее: цикл for внешний или рекурсия? то есть очевидно, что когда мы ставим ферзя в первый ряд, мы можем поставить его на любую клетку в первом ряду, т к он всего один и бить его нечем. Но вот у нас есть внешний цикл for и рекурсия в конце. Так вот, в начале мы ставим ферзя на все позиции, на которых он может стоять, и уже потом разбираемся с каждой ситуацией, или же как только мы нашли позицию, на которой может стоять ферзь, запускаем рекурсию? И если второй вариант, то как мы потом по итогу снова возвращаемся к внешнему циклу for, чтобы посмотреть все возможные варианты расстановки фигуры в определенном ряду? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Программа выполняется последовательно, инструкция за инструкцией. Если какой-то вызов в цикле — то как может *выполниться цикл*, и *не выполниться его часть*? Только вот большое подозрение вызывает отступ последних 3 строк — так, как у вас записано, они выполняются во вложенном цикле...

Comment: никакой приоритетности нет - рекурсивный вызов выполняется так же, как вызов любой другой функции.

Comment: @Harry Я правильно понимаю, что будет так: если, например, найдена позиция, которая удовлетворяет условиям, то мы рекурсивно доходим до конца с этой позицией, а когда эта рекурсия закончится, возвращаемся к внешнему циклу for?

Answer (score 1):

```
1    for j = 1 to n
2      legal = True
3      for i = 1 to r - 1
4        if (Q[i] = j) or (Q[i] = j + r - i) or (Q[i] = j - r + i)
5          legal = False
6      if legal
7        Q[r] = j
8        PlaceQueens(Q[1 .. n],r + 1)
```

Выполнение: строка 1, для `j==1` строка 2, потом цикл 3-5, потом, если `legal` равно `True`, строка 7 и строка 8 — вызов `PlaceQueens(Q[1 .. n],r + 1)`. После возврата из вызова переход к циклу 1, теперь `j==2`, для него строка 2, потом цикл 3-5, потом, если...

Так понятнее?

Comment: Ну то есть к j == 2 мы переходим либо если для j == 1 legal = False, либо если r = n + 1, верно?

Comment: Мы в любом случае по окончании тела цикла переходим к следующему циклу. Что False, что True. Просто при False не выполняются последние две строки, а при True — выполняются.  при чем тут `r == n+1` я вообще не  понимаю — такого условия ни в одном цикле нет. Вы понимаете, ну ощущение, что мы говорим на каких-то разных языках! Да не хочу я разбираться, как работает ваш алгоритм, правильный он или нет, и что там свободно, а что нет. Я поясняю, как работает компьютер, выполняя вашу программу. А вы все хотите в терминах решенной/нерешенной задачи. Да не знает компьютер о вашей задаче ничего.